# Batch file to print list of directory folders and files from a specific subfolder

Tags: batch-file, directory, subdirectory

Please bear with me, I'm a noob to batch files.

So I'm using D:\RDSUsers as my main directory. There are about 150 folders in here (each has a name of a user, for example mine is k.suria ) and I want to look into each user Folder and choose their "Support System" folder that is inside their Desktop Folder. Sounds a bit tricky.

For example my user folder is in D:\RDSUsers\k.suria and I want to get what ever is in my D:\RDSUsers\k.suria\Desktop\System Support folder

In other words I want to to list the Folder names in D:\RDSUsers (150 of them) and list all the files that are in the "System Support" folder that is in everyones Desktop folder, but I want it in one text file.

Did I confuse anyone?

So far I have this:

for /d %%x in (D:\RDSUsers\ *) Do dir %%x\desktop\"Support Systems" > %%x.txt

This prints a 150 text files for each folder from D:\RDSUsers and it lists everything that is in the "Support Systems" folder. The problem is I dont want 150 text files, I'd like just one. How do I get it to print only one text file?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're so close. Just change the end so that you don't make a new file name each time, and add a second `>` so that the output is appended to the existing file:

```
for /d %%x in (D:\RDSUsers\*) Do dir %%x\desktop\"Support Systems" >> OneBigFile.txt
```

Edit: Okay, to get the user/folder name followed by a list of files all on one line, this should do the trick:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d %%x in (D:\RDSUsers\*) do (
    set line=%%~nx
    for %%y in (%%x\desktop\"Support Systems"\*) do set line=!line! %%~nxy  
    echo !line! >> output.txt
)
```

Comment: Oh one more question, if you don't mind. How would I modify it to remove everything else and print only the user folder name and Support Sytem file names?

Comment: There are a couple ways to do that. Something like this should do it:
`for /d %%x in (D:\RDSUsers\*) Do @echo %%x && dir /b %%x\desktop\"Support Systems" >> OneBigFile.txt`
The at sign hides the text of the command itself, echo %%x shows the folder name, and dir /b shows just the file names. If that's not what you're looking for, tell me the exact format you want to see and I'll see if we can match it.

Comment: Almost! It's only listing the file names in the Support Systems folders. It's missing all the folder names that are in the D:\RDSUsers directory (does that make sense?)

Comment: Hmm, it should be listing the folder in RDSUsers and then listing all the file names in it, then listing the next folder from RDSUsers and then listing all the file names in that one. Are you saying you want all of that on one line for each file? You could do something like this: `for /d %%x in (D:\RDSUsers\*) do @ for %%y in (%%x\*) do @ echo %%~nx %%~nxy >> OneBigFile.txt` You can play around with the `echo` part to get different formats, try `echo %%~pnxy` for example.

Comment: If it's possible, I'd like something like this, for example, my folder in the RDSUsers directory is "k.suria". So I want "k.suria" to be printed and all the names of the files in my Support Systems folder. So pretty much like this " k.suria INOUT.lnk  SalesAnalysisViewer.lnk ....etc" (all the .lnk files are in my support systems folder) If its possible to have it in one line that would be great if not anything like that will do. I hope I made sense.